# Convert a Ruby Hash into JSON (without escape characters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization, hash

I have a Hash:

```
my_hash = {"bob.johnson@example.com"=>{"first"=>"Bob", "last"=>"Johnson"}, "lisa.dell@example.com"=>{"first"=>"Lisa", "last"=>"Dell"}}
```

When I try to serialize it with `my_hash.to_json` this is what I get:

```
"{\"bob.johnson@example.com\":{\"first\":\"Bob\",\"last\":\"Johnson\"},\"lisa.dell@example.com\":{\"first\":\"Lisa\",\"last\":\"Dell\"}}"
```

How could I convert a Hash to JSON format without getting the escaping characters?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

These escape characters escape `"` in Ruby `String` (your `my_hash.to_json` output). If you do

```
puts my_hash.to_json
```

you'll see that actually these escape characters aren't added to output string.

Comment: Oh I see, so I assume I'll be just fine going with `my_hash.to_json` in my code?

Comment: @Numbers yes, you should be.

Comment: You need to require the library, it's in the ruby standard library, not in core: `require 'json'`

Comment: @koffeinfrei yeah, I know. OP does too, probably.

Comment: It was a hint to @Numbers, not to you.

Comment: @koffeinfrei there's no reason to think OP doesn't know this fact. After all, he called `to_json` method successfully.

Comment: This will not work if I don't want to print this string, but just send it to other service without the escape chars.

Comment: @D'artanian I don't really understand why you need escape characters to be sent in this case.

Comment: Ruby's "puts" seems to remove the escape chars, but if you pass the json, the receiver gets the unholy mess with backslashes, etc (shows up in the receiver's error log in the params received).  If you use "as json", which does not make a backslashed-mess, it converts all values to strings, when you wanted to preserve ints, decimals, etc.  I am manually building JSON to avoid these two broken methods.   Is there a "convert to json" in ruby which just sends what you gave it "as json"?

Comment: @JosephK Thanks, this was the explanation and answer I was looking for!